# saving a screen shot with renderer.domElement doesn't work on safari

Tags: javascript, safari, three.js

Please see the following video illustrating the problem: http://youtu.be/-QgKo0AsBJs it should just save as a png as it does in Chrome and Firefox. All you get with safari is a blank "unknown" file with no file extension. here is the JS:

```
function getCanvasImg(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('mCanvas');
console.log(renderer.domElement.toDataURL());
var link = document.getElementById('canvasImg');
link.href = renderer.domElement.toDataURL().replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
link.download = 'canvas.png'
link.click();
}
```

furthermore, you will notice the canvas is shifted to the left hand side of the screen; it should be central as it is in the other browsers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Try calling `renderer.render()` right before you call `toDataURL()`.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. console says "TypeError: renderer.render(...) is undefined". I replaced the 5th line with: "link.href = renderer.render().toDataURL().replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");"

Comment: Render the scene again right before you call `toDataURL()`.

Comment: I tried " renderer.domElement.renderer.render().toDataURL().replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");" if that's what you mean?

Comment: `renderer.render( scene, camera ); link.href = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();`

Comment: [Download attribute](http://caniuse.com/#feat=download) not supported in Safari, assuming link is an anchor tag.

Comment: WestLangley, i amended with your code: when i click to download the image it opens in a [new tab](http://i1303.photobucket.com/albums/ag156/eskimo___/snap-and-drag_565_zpskzwmrcfp.jpg), then commad+s(Save) produces unkown.png totally blank - so unfortunately it doesn't appear to be capturing the canvas, but slight improvement thanks as at least the file was appended with w/ ".png"

Comment: 2pha, provided that it doesnt matter that it isnt supported in safari I'd want to dowaload to try; however ive check the link -seems like a good idea - and i cant find a link to download. Im a newby, thanks